# Open in next editor disabled automatically in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Suddenly the open in next editor is disabled automatically in Xcode.

I can't open one more text editor or storyboard. It's disabled for only one project only.

Anyone know how to enable it? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor is focussed.

- Click on the [image] icon
  or
- Select menu View > Editor > Focus or
- Press <kbd>⇧⌥⌘↩</kbd>